# Multiple inheritance of a templated exception class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, exception, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

Why does:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct base_exc : std::runtime_error
{
  base_exc(const std::string& s): std::runtime_error(("base_exc: " + s).c_str()){}
};

struct derived_exc1 : base_exc
{
  derived_exc1(const std::string& s): base_exc(("derived_exc1: " + s).c_str()){}
};

struct derived_exc2 : base_exc
{
  derived_exc2(const std::string& s): base_exc(("derived_exc2: " + s).c_str()){}
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct binary_exc: T1, T2
{
  binary_exc(const std::string& s): T1(s), T2(s){}
};

int main()
{
  try{
    throw binary_exc<derived_exc2, derived_exc1>("something occured");
  }
  catch(base_exc const& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

output:

```sh
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp && ./main
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'binary_exc<derived_exc2, derived_exc1>'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Instead of:

```sh
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp && ./main
base_exc: something occured
```

What I'm trying to achieve: I would like to have two 'orthogonal' classification criteria for certain exceptions in my code, e.g one based on the location in the code (`library1_exc`, `library2_exc`, ...) and one based on categories of errors (`myobject1isoutofbounds_exc`, `myobject2isbroken_exc`, .. ).

These objections could be thrown using something like `throw binary_exc<library2_exc, myobject1isoutofbounds_exc>(msg)` and I would be able to catch them using either:

- the first derived class `catch(library2_exc const& e)`
- the second derived class `catch(myobject1isoutofbounds_exc const& e)`
- the base class `catch(base_exc const& e)`

With my code above the first two - catching with derived classes - work fine, but the last one doesn't. Why? Is there an anti-pattern here?

Note that:

- I read [Exception multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484691/exception-multiple-inheritance) and https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/exception/doc/using_virtual_inheritance_in_exception_types.html, but I couldn't figure out if/how they were related to my problem, in particular with the use of templates.
- I am also completely fine with not using templates, but I am still interested in learning why the code above doesn't work.
- Using virtual inheritance for `binary_exc` produces the same result. (Edit: what I meant when I wrote the ticket was that I tried `struct binary_exc: virtual T1, virtual T2`)
- It seems to me that my question generalizes to N>2 inheritances, but let's start with 2.

Comment: I would have thought the compiler should/would output at least an ambiguity warning/error on the `what` call. Note that Clang on coliru just calls terminate: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df03fe2c07d6a80d.

Comment: Take out the templates and exactly the same thing happens

Comment: Virtual inheritance does not have the same issue, see here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/cpGIMADQBpGlPnkm

Comment: Perfect @linuxfever ! My mistake was that I tried to use virtual inheritance on `base_exc` - i.e `struct binary_exc: virtual T1, virtual T2` - instead of the derived classes - i.e `struct derived_exc2 : virtual base_exc` -.

Comment: Indeed @AlanBirtles this was basically the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484691/exception-multiple-inheritance which I'll mark as duplicate. I did not recognize it probably because I was using templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boost document you linked is your exact problem.  The conversion from `binary_exc` to `base_exc` is ambiguous, and thus the exception handler doesn't match.

When virtual inheritance isn't employed, an object of type `binary_exc<derived_exc1, derived_exc2>` has two `base_exc` sub-objects.  It's laid out like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|   +--------------+  +--------------+   |
|   | +----------+ |  | +----------+ |   |
|   | | base_exc | |  | | base_exc | |   |
|   | +----------+ |  | +----------+ |   |
|   | derived_exc1 |  | derived_exc2 |   |
|   +--------------+  +--------------+   |
| binary_exc<derived_exc1, derived_exc2> |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Since there are two `base_exc` sub-objects, the `binary_exc` object can't be bound to a reference to `base_exc`.  How would the compiler know which `base_exc` object to bind the reference to?

In fact, it doesn't work for the exact same reason the following [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0bec0a4e862023b):

```
struct base {};
struct derived1 : base {};
struct derived2 : base {};
struct derived3 : derived1, derived2 {};

void foo(const base& b) {}

int main() {
    derived3 d3;
    foo(d3);
}
```

---

The solution is to use virtual inheritance:

```
struct base_exc : std::runtime_error
{
  base_exc(const std::string& s): std::runtime_error(("base_exc: " + s).c_str()){}
};

struct derived_exc1 : virtual base_exc // <--- NOTE: added virtual keyword
{
  derived_exc1(const std::string& s): base_exc(("derived_exc1: " + s).c_str()){}
};

struct derived_exc2 : virtual base_exc // <--- NOTE: added virtual keyword
{
  derived_exc2(const std::string& s): base_exc(("derived_exc2: " + s).c_str()){}
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct binary_exc: T1, T2
{
  binary_exc(const std::string& s): base_exc(s), T1(s), T2(s){} // <-- NOTE: added call to base_exc constructor
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6e64c6a51138c96)

Using virtual inheritance, `binary_exc` will have only one `base_exc` sub-object.  It will be laid out like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| +----------+ +--------------+ +--------------+ |
| | base_exc | | derived_exc1 | | derived_exc2 | |
| +----------+ +--------------+ +--------------+ |
|     binary_exc<derived_exc1, derived_exc2>     |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Since there's only one `base_exc` sub-object, the conversion is no longer ambiguous, so a `binary_exc` object can be bound to a reference to `base_exc`.

Note that because `binary_exc` is required to initialize `base_exc`, at least one of the template type parameters must be a class derived from `base_exc`.  You could use some SFINAE tricks to avoid this, but that's something for another question.

Comment: What a great answer, thanks a lot @MilesBudnek! I marked the ticket as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484691/exception-multiple-inheritance but I hope it won't prevent other people from reading your answer...
+1 for the drawings, do you have a tool to generate them?

Comment: @al-dev I used [ASCIIFlow Infinity](http://asciiflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You should use virtual inheritance as described in [this Boost.Exception](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/exception/doc/using_virtual_inheritance_in_exception_types.html) guideline. Particularly in your case, you'd need to derive virtually from `base_exc`.

That way, you avoid the ambiguity when trying to cast the concrete exception type to `base_exc`.

Comment: Thanks @dhavenith ! As explained in the comments above I used the `virtual` keyword on the wrong classes. @linuxfever 's updated code pointed me to the right direction. I can accept this answer but do you mind editing it to include the updated sections of the code?