# Why do programmers use both std::bad_alloc and std::exception. Is std::exception alone not sufficient

Tags: c++, exception

Consider the following code snippet

```
try {
    goesWrong();
}
catch (const std::bad_alloc &e)
{
    std::cout << "Catching bad_alloc: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
    std::cout << "Catching exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Why do we need to catch a lot of individual exceptions. Just `std::exception` at the end is enough to catch all exceptions isn't it ? Why an extra 4 lines of code to catch `std::bad_alloc` explicitly when `std::exception` is going to catch it anyway?

Comment: To have specific message for `std::bad_alloc` ?

Comment: But e.what() is going to provide an explanatory string anyway. isn't it

Comment: But they want to print `Catching bad_alloc:` beforehand, can't do that in the `std::exception` handler.

Comment: There could be cases where they want to do something more specific than only printing the value using `e.what`...

Comment: Got it now! Thanks folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separate catch statements are so that you have have different behaviour depending on the type of exception thrown.

For example you might be expecting a `bad_alloc` and can recover from it by trying again with a smaller allocation or by freeing memory elsewhere.

> Just std::exception at the end is enough to catch all exceptions isn't it ?

No, catching `std::exception` is enough to catch all thrown exceptions which are derived from `std::exception`. In c++ `std::exception` doesn't have any special meaning, you can throw any type as an exception. It is recommended to derive from `std::exception` but not required.

There are even pitfalls like if you have multiple inheritance and your exception class derives from `std::exception` [twice it won't be caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484691/exception-multiple-inheritance).

To catch all exceptions you need to catch `...`:

```
struct my_exception {};

try
{
  switch ( i )
  {
  case 1:
    throw std::runtime_error( "i is 1" );
  case 2:
    // bad idea, who is responsible for freeing the exception? But perfectly legal
    throw new std::runtime_error( "i is 1" );
  case 3:
    // you can throw numbers too
    throw i;
  case 4:
    throw my_exception();
  }
}
catch ( const std::exception& )
{
}
catch ( const my_exception& )
{
}
catch ( ... )
{
}
```

Comment: Alan,  i don't quite get this point - There are even pitfalls like if you have multiple inheritance and your exception class derives from std::exception twice it won't be caught. Could you pl elaborate ?

Comment: @badri see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484691/exception-multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 3):

> Why do we need to catch a lot of individual exceptions.

In general, because that allows different behaviour depending on the type of the caught exception.

In this case, there's need to do so, since this possibility is not taken advantage of.

Consider for example a case where you have allocated a large cache in memory. In that case, when catching `std::bad_alloc`, you might release the cache and try again, while that approach would not be useful in the case of other exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

`exception` could be any expception while `bad_alloc` is more specific. Not only you might want to react differently for different kind of exceptions, but also it more clearly expresses what is going on. After all code is written to express your intention not just to make it work somehow.

Answer (score 1):

More an addition to the answers given so far than a separate, own one:

Actually, you *could* base exception handling on evaluation of the `what()` string:

```
catch(std::exception const& e)
{
    if(strcmp(e.what(), "some text"))
    {
        doThis();
    }
    else if(strstr(e.what(), "something"))
    {
        doThat();
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, this requires that you know the exact string contents. What, if these differ across different C++ implementations? What, if these are localised on some systems? Do you really want to cope with all such matters? Additionally, text processing is much more expensive than just catching different exceptions.

So with different exceptions, you gain portability, safety (consider typos in the strings you compare with...), easier and better readable code and, as a bonus, efficiency.